# PowerShell: Create an event handler when an assembly is loaded

Tags: .net, events, powershell

I'm interested in running some PowerShell code whenever a .NET assembly has been loaded into a PowerShell session using the `Add-Type` cmdlet or `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile()`.

I don't see any events on the [.NET `Assembly` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that would allow me to accomplish this task.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Background

When you load a .NET `Assembly` into your PowerShell session, you're really loading the .NET `Assembly` into what's called a .NET `AppDomain`. Every single .NET process has at least one `AppDomain`, and create and destroy other `AppDomain` objects. The default `AppDomain` can be referenced in PowerShell using `[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain;`. The `AppDomain` instance returned by the `CurrentDomain` static property has a .NET event named `AssemblyLoad`, per the [MSDN documentation for the class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

### Subscribing to the Event

What you need to do is subscribe to the `AssemblyLoad` event on the "current" `AppDomain`, and declare the script code that you'd like to run when that event is thrown. We do this through the `Register-ObjectEvent` cmdlet, which allows us to subscribe to an event on a .NET object.

```
# 0. Clean up event subscriptions
Get-EventSubscriber | Unregister-Event;

# 1. Get the current AppDomain
$AppDomain = [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain;
# 2. Declare a ScriptBlock that will execute when the event is fired
$Action = { Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green -Object 'Assembly was loaded!'; };
# 3. Register the event subscription
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $AppDomain -EventName AssemblyLoad -Action $Action -OutVariable EventSubscription -SourceIdentifier AssemblyLoad;
```

The `-SourceIdentifier` parameter allows us to specify a friendly name for the event subscription, that we can later use to retrieve it via the [`Get-EventSubscriber` cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849963.aspx). The `-OutVariable` parameter is a common parameter to all PowerShell cmdlets, that allows us to define a variable name that will store all of the output that is generated from the cmdlet.

### Cleaning Up

Here is an example of retrieving the event subscription, after it has been registered:

```
Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier AssemblyLoad;
```

To unregister the event subscription, after you are finished with it, simply pipe the event subscription into the [`Unregister-Event` cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849896.aspx), similar to the following example.

```
Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier AssemblyLoad | Unregister-Event;
```